# How to use vue-i18n in custom VuePress components?

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I'm using the [VuePress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/) framework to build a multilingual website for my project. The [Internationalization Guide](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/i18n.html) in the VuePress docs is quite helpful, but it doesn't explain, how to translate [custom Vue.js components](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#using-components) in the `.vuepress/components/` directory.

From what I gathered, the best solution would be to integrate the [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) plugin with VuePress, but there appears to be no guidance on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the perfect solution, but it works as intended:

1. Follow the [Internationalization Guide](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/i18n.html) and set up multiple locales.
2. Install [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/): `npm i vue-i18n`.
3. Assuming you are using the default theme, we will extend that to hook vue-i18n into it. Create a custom theme directory: `mkdir ./.vuepress/theme/`.
4. Add an `index.js` file to the newly created theme directory:

```js
// .vuepress/theme/index.js

module.exports = {
  extend: '@vuepress/theme-default' // extend the default VuePress theme
}
```

5. Install vue-i18n by adding another file to the same directory, the `enhanceApp.js` file which allows you to do some [App Level Enhancements](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/writing-a-theme.html#app-level-enhancements):

```js
// .vuepress/theme/enhanceApp.js

import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

export default ({ Vue, options }) => {
  Vue.use(VueI18n);

  options.i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
  });
}
```

6. In your custom components, you can set the current locale passing on the global computed property [`$lang`](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/global-computed.html#lang):

```js
// .vuepress/components/Foo.vue

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$i18n.locale = this.$lang;
  },
  i18n: {
    messages: {
      'en-US': { title: 'Foo' },
      'de-DE': { title: 'Bar' }
    }
  }
};
```

I found no simple solution to hook into the root component to set the current locale globally. Maybe someone else has a hint on how to achieve this nicely?